# CBPeripheral name. Encoding issue

Tags: encoding, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

I want that to change is the peripheral name that is shown at iOS Bluetooth settings and in my app, so that user can identify the device.

What I do is:

1. User writes a name in a UITextField and I get the NSString.
2. I convert NSString to NSData.
3. A characteristic is written with the new peripheral name.
4. Peripheral change GATT device name.

All works fine if I use UTF8 encoding to get NSData, but have problems with tildes, written accents and cyrillic alphabet, because app supports multiple languages. Not sure if problem is with iOS device or peripheral.

My questions:

1. What encoding should I use?
2. Is it posible use this characters for names?
3. What encoding is used for the returned string when peripheral.name is called?
4. Is there another kind of solution to change the peripheral name that is shown?

Comment: What stack do your use in the external peripheral? Does it support arbitrary names? The specification states the name is a utf8s so in theory it should accept any legal string. What does "have problems with..." mean? Have you tried sniffing the BLE packages to see if the peripheral transmits the name you set?

Comment: @allprog. Thanks for your reply. I did not find the encoding for the name property. You were right and it is UTF8. My problem was that I did not realized that some characters needs 2 bytes. So the problem was related to length.

Comment: Great! I added an answer for future reference. You can accept it or post your own and accept that. I think it is very important to not leave this question open in any case and indicate future users that you found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name is encoded in UTF-8 which is in accordance with the specification. [UTF-8 is a multibyte coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), so interpreting the byte values as separate characters can lead to unexpected results.